# counting number of elements less than X in a BST

Tags: c++, c++11, search, binary-search-tree

I had implemented a BST for a multiset using the C++ code below, whereas each node contains the number of occurrence `num` of each distinct number `data`, and I try to find the number of elements less than certain value x, using the `order` function below.

It works, however, inefficient in terms of execution time.
Is there any method with better time complexity?

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    int height;
    int num;

    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};
```

```
int order(Node *n, int x) {
    int sum = 0;
    if (n != NULL) {
        if (n->data < x) {
            sum += n->num;
            sum += order(n->right, x);
        }
        sum += order(n->left, x);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What's Node::num?

Comment: the number of occurrence of that number (data), for example, if 2 appears once, the node representing it will have data=2 and num=1

Comment: In general, recursive functions are not the most efficient.  Observe how many identical copies of `int x` are made.

Comment: Another observation - if `Node` had a "parent" pointer, you could walk the entire tree without any need of a stack.

Comment: I don't think you can go faster, unless you store more data in each node (but then the insertion would take longer). E.g. each node could contain the total number of values in the whole subtree rooted in it. Then for `n->data < x` you'd have the answer ready, and would only need to inspect the left subtree when `n->data >= x`. This then  will become a tail recursion, and could be converted to iteration.

Comment: @DrewDormann too much fuss is being made about this parent pointer thing. You can go without and the BST may still behave [as if it had one](https://github.com/user1095108/xsg). It's an implementation detail, IMO. This sort of school questions don't require that sort of deep thinking anyway.

Comment: @user1095108 it was certainly not my intention to make too much fuss.

Comment: Sound as [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please explain exacly what is your task. Do you have to implement BST tree yourself? Can you use standard library? What is the input what output of the program? Note that storing values in BST doesn't have to be best solution for your mysterious problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring the algorithm down to O(logN) time by storing in each node the number of elements in the subtree of which it is the root. Then you'd only have to recurse on one of the two children of each node (go left if `x < node->data`, right if `x > node->data`), which if the tree is balanced only takes logarithmic time.

```cpp
struct Node {
    int data;
    int height;
    int num;
    int size; // numer of elements in the subtree starting at this node

    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

int order(Node *n, int x) {
    if(n == NULL) return 0;

    // elements less than n->data make up the whole left subtree
    if (x == n->data) {
        return n->left ? n->left->size : 0;
    }
    // even smaller? just recurse left
    else if (x < n->data) {
        return order(n->left, x);
    }
    // bigger? take the whole left subtree and part of the right one
    else {
        return (n->left ? n->left->size : 0) + order(n->right, x);
    }
}
```

Of course, now you have to keep track of the size, but this can be done very efficiently when updating the tree: simply recalculate the size (`n->left->size + n->right->size + 1`) of each modified node in an insertion or deletion.

Comment: Usually items are inserted to BST  in random order os how `size` of each item is updated when new item is added without complexity penalty?

Comment: @MarekR when inserting you travel down a path in the tree, simply recalculate the size at the end of the recursive function so that you update the path from the bottom. In this way you update all nodes that may have changed at the same cost of the insertion by itself which is logarithmic. The same thing goes for deletion, update when going back up

Answer (score 0):

If you can add the size to your structure, I highly recommend using Dario Petrillo’s answer.

If you have to stick to your structure, you can reduce the number of instructions and recursions.

```
int count_all(Node* n) {
    int acc = n->num;
    if (n->left != NULL) acc += count_all(n->left);
    if (n->right != NULL) acc += count_all(n->right);
    return acc;
}

int order(Node *n, int x) {
    if (n == NULL) return 0;
    
    // Find the first left node which is < x
    while (n->data >= x) {
        n = n->left;
        if (n == NULL) return 0;
    }
    
    assert(n != NULL && n->data < x);
    
    int sum = n->num;
    
    // Grab everything left because all of them are < x
    if (n->left != NULL) sum += count_all(n->left);
    
    // Some of the right nodes may be < x, some may not
    // Repeat the algorithm to find out
    if (n->right != NULL) sum += order(n->right, x);

    return sum;
}
```

This reduces the number of recursions when the root is bigger than `x` and you want to quickly find the next left node that satisfies `n->data < x`. It also removes a ton of unnecessary comparisons to `x` for the left side of a tree where you already know that everything is `< x`.